# Subversion without Apache

Tags: linux, svn

I'm trying to setup a subversion repository without apache (my webserver is using Lighttpd)
Is there anyway I can do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure - you can use one of two access methods that don't rely on apache. The first is using the included [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html) daemon. The other option is to use [svn+ssh](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/531.cfm).

Comment: One additional comment - if you need a web repository viewer, you can look into ViewVC, which I believe can run under lighttpd.

Comment: Yeah I'm going to use trac for vewing, do you now if it's possible to checkout without SSH?